# Calling config on a BehaviorSpec test in kotlintest

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest

Is it possible to configure individual test cases in a `BehaviorSpec` in kotlintest?

For `StringSpec` tests it is possible to do like so:

```
class MyTest : StringSpec({
    "this is a test".config(...) {}
})
```

I can't seem to do the same for a `BehaviorSpec`. I'd expect something like:

```
class MyTest : BehaviorSpec({
    Given("a foo") {
        When("baring") {
            Then("bazzing") {

            }.config(...)
        }
    }
})
```

According to [this](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/142) supposedly solved issue, this is already implemented. But as far as I can see (using version 3.1.8 of kotlintest) `Then` returns `Unit`...

Comment: You're absolutely right. https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/issues/495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in release 3.2

Now you can do something like.

```
class BehaviorSpecExample : AbstractBehaviorSpec() {

  init {
    given("a sheet of string cells 4x4") {
      `when`("get existing cell by reference (like A1 or B2)") {
        then("should contain its value").config(invocations = 3) {
          // test here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.